# AWS EC2 Connect Database from another server

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

in my region, AWS doesn't have small databases just large,
so I want to connect my EC2 node project to MySQL from another server like

> BlueHost MySQL, etc

**both of Ec2 and databases services in one region**

**it's just that the available size of AWS databases in my region, So Large
and I don't even need a Quarter of these databases**

is it possible?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more for the infrastructure? Are both servers in AWS (different regions) or is one in another cloud, or maybe on premise?

Comment: in my region the EC2 and databases services are available and I use EC2 already, but the difference is that the available size of the databases is very large, there are no free or small databases and I don't want to use theme

Comment: OK so you want your database to be in another region?

Comment: I want my database to be in another host, not in AWS, then connect my project with the database, but it doesn't  matter if I can use database from another region from the same host (AWS) that will be great

Comment: sorry if my English is broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a detail of the various options that you have, based on your scenario you are trying to rehost your database from its current host to another.

As you're using MySQL you can make use of the managed [RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/) service, [Aurora MySQL](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/) or an EC2 host either within the same region or a different region.

If the VPC is different (this would be the case in a different region) you can establish a [peering connection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html) between the VPC. You will need to make sure that the security groups allow inbound access from the source of the other VPCs CIDR. You should also ideally keep the database as a private instance to avoid any malicious public ingress.

If the database is instead migrated to either another cloud or on-premise you would need to establish a connection between the 2 networks. AWS provides VPN solutions for both [site to site VPN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/VPC_VPN.html) and [client VPN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/what-is.html) so this is worth exploring. Additionally there are third party VPN solutions on the [AWS marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace) such as OpenVPN.

Finally ensure you are aware that there will be an increased latency between regions, for an overview of this latency take a look at [Cloudpings AWS latency](https://www.cloudping.co/grid) page.